# Visual Studio Target Framework Greyed out

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 v16.8.5 and this morning I found that my solution which targets .net5.0 could not build and had the error:

> The TargetFramework value 'net5.0-windows' was not recognized. It may
> be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or
> TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.

If I go into the project properties the Target Framework combobox is greyed out.
If I create a new solution, the combobox is still greyed out (however, the new solution targets .net3.1 and builds fine).

I didn't have this problem yesterday and I haven't installed any updates.
I've also checked I don't have any global.json files in my solution as suggested in a similar post.

[image: Properties dialog box]

My property group is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>

    <RootNamespace>Drain</RootNamespace>

    <ApplicationIcon>icon_vRx_icon.ico</ApplicationIcon>

    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>

    <AssemblyVersion>0.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>

    <FileVersion>0.0.0.1</FileVersion>

    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Any suggestions what might have happened?

Comment: I am using .net5.0 and viusal studio2019 but no problem. You can try to use this method.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1013

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to reply you so late:

Currently `.Net 5.0` is not supported, it is recommended that you upgrade to `.Net 6.0` as soon as possible.

There is no problem in copying your property group under my `2019 16.11.13 version`, you could try to update the version.

I suggest you go to the `visual studio installer` to check whether the `.Net 5.0 Runtime` is installed correctly (you could try to reinstall).

[image]

- Finally, I want to ask, will you encounter the same problem when you create a new .Net 5.0 WPF project?

Comment: @Richard，I have made an answer about it. Do you have time to check it?